# Adding modal to my page. How to make full block not to only <section> how add modal with stylise <div> and <span>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog

i'm new here, i begginer and i have problem with my project.
I used template "Landed" https://html5up.net/landed - i modyfing it, and i have problem with adding a functionality: full size modal for images.

I just need to make full size modal after clicking image.
It would be nice if also images were cropped to same size, and user click to it to see full picture.
I need it for showing my graphic portfolio.

I tried to add this code by @snowMonkey
https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/f1zav0ge/

I asked my friends, but they dont know what to do.

I tired many ways (changing in javaScript, and messing with classes), but i cannot achive what i want.
It works without styling `<div class="col-4 col-6-xsmall"><span class="image fit">` but shadow makes from  to end page - i need shadow to full page.

if i add to code this styling i see just black after choosing image, or sometimes "undefined".
Could someone help me?
Thanks.

Codes

HTML:

```
<section>
                <div class="box alt">
                    <div class="row gtr-50 gtr-uniform">
```

```
                </div>
            </section>

        
            <!--
        <section>
            
            <img class="myImages" id="myImg" src="http://onebigphoto.com/uploads/2012/10/midnight-sun-in-lofoten-norway.jpg" alt="Midnight sun in Lofoten, Norway" width="300" height="200">
            <img class="myImages" id="myImg" src="http://cdn-image.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/1490029386/fisherman-cabin-hamnoy-lofoten-islands-norway-NORWAY0320.jpg?itok=cpPuUjh1" alt="Fishermen's cabins in Lofoten, Norway" width="300" height="200">
            <img class="myImages" id="myImg" src="http://fjordtours.blob.core.windows.net/fjordtours-umbraco/1199/gerirangerfjord-per-ottar-walderhaug-fjordnorway.jpg" alt="Gerirangerfjord, Norway" width="300" height="200">
            -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* modal */

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  #myImg:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  .modal {
    overflow-y: none;
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px;
    /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Full width */
    height: 100%;
    /* Full height */
    overflow: auto;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    /* Black w/ opacity */
  }
  
  .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
  }
  
  #caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
  }
  
  .modal-content,
  #caption {
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
  }
  
  @keyframes zoom {
    from {
      transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
      transform: scale(1)
    }
  }
  
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .modal-content {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
    
/*koniec*/

/* Image */

    .image {
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .image:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

        .image:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            /*background-image: url("images/overlay.png");*/
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .image img {
            border-radius: 4px;
            display: block;
        }

        .image.left {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 1.5em 1em 0;
            top: 0.25em;
        }

        .image.right {
            float: right;
            margin: 0 0 1em 1.5em;
            top: 0.25em;
        }

        .image.left, .image.right {
            max-width: 40%;
        }

            .image.left img, .image.right img {
                width: 100%;
            }

        .image.fit {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 0 2em 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .image.fit img {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .modal {
                display: none; /* Hidden by default */
                position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
                z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
                padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%; /* Full width */
                height: 100%; /* Full height */
                overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
            }
            
            /* Modal Content (image) */
            .modal-content {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 80%;
                max-width: 700px;
            }
            
            /* Caption of Modal Image */
            #caption {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 80%;
                max-width: 700px;
                text-align: center;
                color: #ccc;
                padding: 10px 0;
                height: 150px;
            }
            
            /* Add Animation */
            .modal-content, #caption {    
                -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
                animation-name: zoom;
                animation-duration: 0.6s;
            }
            
            @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
                from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
                to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
            }
            
            @keyframes zoom {
                from {transform:scale(0)} 
                to {transform:scale(1)}
            }
            
            /* The Close Button */
            .close {
                position: absolute;
                top: 15px;
                right: 35px;
                color: #f1f1f1;
                font-size: 40px;
                font-weight: bold;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }
            
            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #bbb;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            
            /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
            @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
                .modal-content {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
```

JS:

```
    // create references to the modal...
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// to all images -- note I'm using a class!
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('col-4 col-6-xsmall');
// the image in the modal
var modalImg = document.getElementById("image fit");
// and the caption in the modal
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

// Go through all of the images with our custom class
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  // and attach our click listener for this image.
  img.onclick = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: I tried change span class to image fit and other methods, but still cannot achive what i want. Adding id to image doeas not work too

Comment: No one know how solve this problem?

Comment: I solved a part of problem, but my modal still no view to full page but from <section> to end of page.